# ActionScript 3 coding error

Tags: properties, actionscript, undefined

I need a little bit of help with some code issue. I am trying to connect to the server from a click of a button. When I execute the code I receive this error in my output: 1120: Access of undefined property nc.close

Which is strange because I already declared the nc property in the btnStart function. I have been tweaking around with the code but I keep getting the same annoying error. If you have any suggestions how to resolve this that be great!
Thanks

Code is below:

```
btn_One.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnStart);

btn_Two.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClose);

 function btnStart(event:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("Connecting...");
    var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
    nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
    nc.connect("rtmfp://localhost/streamingLive");

}
//// ERROR LINE NC.CLOSE();
function btnClose(event:MouseEvent):void{
   trace("Closing time");
   nc.close();
```

}

```
function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void{
    switch(event.info.code){
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
        trace("Awesome connection");
        break;

        case "NetConnection.Connect.Failed":
        trace("Unable to connect");
        break;

        case "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected":
        trace("WHoooops");
        break;

        case "NetGroup.Connect.Success":
        trace("GroupConnection");
        break;

        case "NetGroup.Connect.Failed":
        trace("Group failed");
        break;

        case "NetGroup.Connect.Rejected":
        trace("Ouch!!!");
        break;

        var ns:NetStream = new NetStream();
       ns.publish("live", "streaming");
        ns.attachCamera();
        ns.attachAudio();
        ns.connect(nc);

        var ng:NetGroup = new NetGroup(nc,    groupspec.groupspecWithAuthorizations());
        ng.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);


    }
}

var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
cam.setMode(420, 320, 15);
cam.setQuality(0, 85);

cam.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, statusHandler);

var vid:Video = new Video();
vid.width = cam.width;
vid.height = cam.height;
vid.x = 100;
vid.y = 100;

vid.attachCamera(cam);
addChild(vid);

var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
mic.gain = 50;
mic.framesPerPacket = 1;
mic.setSilenceLevel(0, 2000);
mic.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;

//camera access permissions
function statusHandler(event:StatusEvent):void 
{ 
    switch (event.code) 
    { 
        case "Camera.Muted": 
            trace("User clicked Deny."); 
            break; 
        case "Camera.Unmuted": 
            trace("User clicked Accept."); 
            break; 
    } 
}

//audio access permissions
function micStatus(event:StatusEvent):void 
{ 
    if (event.code == "Microphone.Unmuted") 
    { 
        trace("Microphone access was allowed."); 
    }  
    else if (event.code == "Microphone.Muted") 
    { 
         trace("Microphone access was denied."); 
    } 
}

//array of camera names
var cameraA:Array = Camera.names;



for ( var i : int = 0; i < cameraA.length; i++){

     trace ( "Camera: ", cameraA[i] );

}

var groupspec:GroupSpecifier = new GroupSpecifier("groupone");
groupspec.multicastEnabled = true;
//group postings
groupspec.postingEnabled = true;
//specific peer posting
groupspec.routingEnabled = true;
//automatic peer discovery
groupspec.serverChannelEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nc` is declared inside one function, but you're trying to use it inside of another function.  Sometimes you can just pass the variable around as an argument, but in this case, that won't really work out too well.  So in this case, do the following:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();

function btnStart(event:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("Connecting...");
    // var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection(); // removed
    nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
    nc.connect("rtmfp://localhost/streamingLive");
}

//// ERROR LINE NC.CLOSE();
function btnClose(event:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("Closing time");
    nc.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi Panzercrisis, Your code worked just fine! You saved me a lot of hassle. Big thank you